Accesing .env in Node.js / Express.js
import validator from 'validator';
import { Users } from '../../models/auth.js';
import { jwtSignPromise } from '../../utils/jasonWebToken.js';

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const JWT_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

export const login = async (req, res) => {
    const initialStateResponse = {
        userName: null,
        token: null,
// ........ more code ..............

I'm using "type": "module" in package.json, and import method shouldn't be the problem.
The only why I found to access .env file, it's by importing dotenv, and calling to dotenv.config() in every file I need to use process.env.ANY_VALUE
Is there a better and correct why to be able to use process.env without the other 2 lines in every file?

According to the dotenv docs:

As early as possible in your application, import and configure dotenv

So the problem in the provided code is that dotenv called after other modules (auth.js, jasonWebToken.js), which means when you run the program, first it imports these modules (with all their code), and only after that populates process.env, so updated process.env. is not available in top level code in the imported modules.
How To Fix
Consider importing/invoking as early as possible:
import "dotenv/config";
import validator from 'validator';

import { Users } from '../../models/auth.js';
import { jwtSignPromise } from '../../utils/jasonWebToken.js';

const JWT_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

Alternative approach for Node.js 20+
Starting from version 20.6.0, Node.js supports new --env-file cli option to load env vars from a file:
node --env-file=.env index.js


The first snippet won't work by specs because import statements are hosted above anything else.

@EstusFlask thanks for pointing out! I likely never had issues with this approach because rarely using process.env in top level code. I've updated the snippet to use the dotenv/config shorthand, which should work for all cases.

I dislike relying on import order for my application to work correctly, as this behavior is too brittle and hidden. I also don't like having to run dotenv over and over again.
I found that the easiest thing is for only 1 file to load dotenv, and for that file to re-export the variables for the application.
This central config script is a great place to do validation of environment variables, makes it easy to discover which variables are supported across the application and also lets you more easily have strict typing around your configuration.

``import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const JWT_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
const EMAIL_PASS = process.env.GMAIL_COM_APP_KEY;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
export { JWT_KEY, EMAIL_PASS, PORT };``
Yes, I thought this way after making this post, this was my solution.
Does it seem to what you explain?
